# Tensor product in algebra and analysis

Tags: integration, measure-theory, tensor-products, convolution

In what sens the tensor product of two measures or two function is similaire to algebraic tensor product. 
In other words: what is the relation between the tensor product in the contexte of analysis and the contexte of algebra ??

Comment: Is [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670235/is-the-product-of-sigma-algebras-a-tensor-product-in-some-sense) helpful to you? Are you looking for a characterization in terms of some universal property?

Comment: The theory of tensor product in the category of Banach spaces (or more generally locally convex topological spaces) goes back to Grothendieck and has its subtleties. You can find introductions in Ryan's book https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781852334376 or in Dienstel's https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-52.